# AttributeError at /profile/1/ 'User' object has no attribute 'room_set

Tags: python, django

I created profile page and out of nowhere it just broke. Everything was working fine but then it just broke outta nowhere. I have no clue what's wrong

Here is my code and traceback. Let me know if more detail and code is needed.

views.py

```
def userProfile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    rooms = user.room_set.all()
    room_messages = user.message_set.all()
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    context = {'user': user, 'rooms': rooms, 
               'room_messages': room_messages, 'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'authentication/profile.html', context)
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issuetracker\users\views.py", line 59, in userProfile
    rooms = user.room_set.all()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profile/1/
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'room_set'
```

models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='host')
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='topic')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    assigned = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='assigned')
    status = models.BooleanField(choices=STATUS, default=True)
    priority = models.TextField(choices=PRIORITIES, default='None', max_length=10)
    type = models.TextField(choices=TYPE, default='Misc', max_length=15)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='participants', blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

models.py User

```
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, default="avatar.svg")

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Comment: Looks like you have a Room model with a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField relationship with the User model, can you share this Room model?

Comment: Share your `Room` and `User` model.

Comment: @mdaw11 you have three relationships from Room to User, a little excessive, you need to use the `related_name` from one of those fields instead of `room_set` - `host`, `assigned` or `participants`